# Unable to create a constant value of type. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

```
readonly IDbSet<Company> _Companies;

_Companies = _uow.Set<Company>();

public IList<Company> GetAllByGroupNames(IList<CompanyGroupMappings> CompanyGroupMappings)
{
    return _Companies.Where(o => companyGroupMappings.Select(p => p.GroupName).Contains(o.GroupName)).ToList();
}
```

This returns an error:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'CompanyGroupMappings'. 
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
{System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}

How do I have to change it? Is it regarding the first list not being in the memory?

Comment: Duplicate with lots of upvotes - please do try to search for an answer before opening a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code as below:

```
return _Companies.Where(o => CompanyGroupMappings.Any(p => p.GroupName == o.GroupName)).ToList();
```

Make sure to pass a `List<CompanyGroupMappings>` rather than `IList<CompanyGroupMappings>`